# Convert IEnumerable<Object> to Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I want to convert an `IEnumerable`, defined below:

```
public class NameVal 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<NameVal> contents =  new List<NameVal>()
{
    new NameVal { Name = "title", Content = "My new post" },
    new NameVal { Name = "body", Content = "This is my first post!" }
};
```

to the anonymous type `data`:

```
var data = new
{
    title = "My new post",
    body = "This is my first post!"
};
```

Does anyone know how to go about this?  Thanks.

Comment: you could use a dictionary of string, string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use an `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic`:

```
var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
foreach (NameVal nameVal in contents) {
    x.Add(nameVal.Name, nameVal.Content);
}

dynamic d = x;
Console.WriteLine(d.title);
Console.WriteLine(d.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Try this

```
var data = contents.Select(x => new
{
    title = x.Name,
    body = x.Content
});
```

Comment: Which will give the wrong output... you'd get 2 items rather than 1, and only the `body` property of the second item would have the correct value.